# How to remove and count words from a text file?

Tags: vb.net, information-retrieval

I want to find the term Frequency and Invert Document Frequency (TF-IDF) for a text files in the particular collection of files.

So in this case I just want to calculate the total words in file, number of occurrences of particular word in the file and to remove the words like `a`, `an`, `the`, etc.

Is there any parser in vb.net?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: go through this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/302262/How-to-search-specific-string-into-text-file-from) and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most easier way i know is something like:

```
Private Function CountWords(Filename as String) As Integer
    Return IO.File.ReadAllText(Filename).Split(" ").Count 
End Function
```

If you want to delete words you can:

```
Private Sub RemoveWords (Filename as String, DeleteWords as List(Of String))
    Dim AllWords() As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(Filename).Split(" ")
    Dim RemainingWords() As String = From Word As String In AllWords
                                     Where DeleteWords.IndexOf(Word) = -1

    'Do something with RemainingWords ex:
    'IO.File.WriteAllText(Filename, String.Join(vbNewLine, RemainingWords)
End Sub
```

This assume that words are separated with space

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to read the text file into a single string, and then use the .NET framework to find the match:

```
Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText("D:\Temp\MyFile.txt")
Dim index As Integer = text.IndexOf("hello")
If index >= 0 Then
   ' String is in file, starting at character "index"
End If
```

Or solution 2 You need StreamReader and Regx for that.

```
//read file content in StreamReader
StreamReadertxt Reader = new StreamReader(fName);
szReadAll = txtReader.ReadToEnd();//Reads the whole text file to the end
txtReader.Close(); //Closes the text file after it is fully read.
txtReader = null;
//search word in file content
if (Regex.IsMatch(szReadAll, "SearchME", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))//If the match is found in allRead
  MessageBox.Show("found");
else
  MessageBox.Show("not found");
```

Thats all, i hope this resolves your queries.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx) would help you:

```
Using System.IO
Using System.Text.RegularExpressions

...

Dim anyWordPattern As String = "\b\w+\b"
Dim myWordPattern As String = "\bMyWord\b"
Dim replacePattern As String = "\b(?<sw>a|an|the)\b"
Dim content As String = File.ReadAllText(<file name>)
Dim coll = Regex.Matches(content, anyWordPattern)
Console.WriteLine("Total words: {0}", coll.Count)
coll = Regex.Matches(content, myWordPattern, RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Console.WEriteLine("My word occurrences: {0}", coll.Count)
Dim replacedContent = Regex.Replace(content, replacePattern, String.Empty, RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Console.WriteLine("Replaced content: {0}", replacedContent)
```

Explanation for regular expressions used:

- \b - word boundary;
- \w - any word character;
- + - quantifier, 1 or many;
- (?...) - named group, called "sw" - stop word
- a|an|the - alternatives, "a" or "an" or "the"

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
Dim text As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\file.txt")
Dim wordsToSearch() As String = New String() {"Hello", "World", "foo"}
Dim words As New List(Of String)()
Dim findings As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Integer))

'Dividing into words'
words.AddRange(text.Split(New String() {" ", Environment.NewLine()}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
'Discarting all the words you dont want'
words.RemoveAll(New Predicate(Of String)(AddressOf WordsDeleter))

findings = SearchWords(words, wordsToSearch)

Console.WriteLine("Number of 'foo': " & findings("foo").Count)
```

And the functions used:

```
Private Function WordsDeleter(ByVal obj As String) As Boolean
    Dim wordsToDelete As New List(Of String)(New String() {"a", "an", "then"})
    Return wordsToDelete.Contains(obj.ToLower)
End Function

Private Function SearchWords(ByVal allWords As List(Of String), ByVal wordsToSearch() As String) As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Integer))
    Dim dResult As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Integer))()
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    For Each s As String In wordsToSearch
        dResult.Add(s, New List(Of Integer))

        While i >= 0 AndAlso i < allWords.Count
            i = allWords.IndexOf(s, i)
            If i >= 0 Then dResult(s).Add(i)
            i += 1
        End While
    Next

    Return dResult
End Function
```